# Shortcut to a mono .exe file

Tags: shortcuts, mono

How can have a shortcut to a compiled mono program (.exe). The execution command in command line is "mono MYPROGRAM.exe"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just create a launcher in your desktop..

Right click in your desktop-->Click Create Launcher

It will bring a window.In the name field you can write wat ever name you want..In the command field type `mono /path/to/the/MYPROGRAM.exe` without quotes thats it.

Now you can click this shortcut to launch your program.

Comment: The path to the .exe file?

Comment: You have to mention the path for your program                 **mono /path/to/the/fie.exe**

Comment: Please provide `*.desktop` file

Comment: Right click on ubuntu 16.04 desktop doesn't show "Create Launcher"